# How to select an attribute value in an XML and concatenate it with a string and use it as an attribute value in a new XML using XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing

I need to transform an existing XML into another XML using XSLT.

The problem I am facing is that I need to use the "typeName" attribute from the ECClass and concatenate it with http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1#

The XML i am working with is -

```
<ECSchema>
    <ECClass typeName="ABC">
        <BaseClass>PQR</BaseClass>
        <BaseClass>XYZ</BaseClass>
    </ECClass>
    <ECClass typeName="IJK">
        <BaseClass>MNO</BaseClass>
        <BaseClass>DEF</BaseClass>
    </ECClass>
<ECSchema>
```

For example the concatenated result should be -

http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1#ABC for the first ECClass

I need to set this string as the attribute value of rdf:about in the owl:class tag in the new XML structure.

The new XML structure is -

```
<owl:ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1">
    <owl:class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1#ABC">
    </owl:class>
    <owl:class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1#ABC">
    </owl:class>
</owl:ontology>
```

Right now I have not yet tried to do anything about the BaseClass. I have only been trying to convert the ECCLass to owl:class.

The XSL for it is -

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="ECSchema/ECClass">
        <owl:class rdf:about="<xsl:value-of select="concat('http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1#' , '@typeName') />" >
        </owl:class>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

I have been trying many combinations to do this from various sources but haven't been able to do it.

It always returns an error - "**Additional information: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character**."

Can anybody please help me with this as I am very new to XSLT and all I have been getting is lots of errors.

Comment: your links are broken

Comment: These links only work in protege application as the are not meant for web. They are generated by the application. So I have just tried to emulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags cannot be nested. To achieve your purpose, you should learn about [*attribute value templates*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates). In addition, your code is rather sloppy. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1">
        <xsl:for-each select="ECSchema/ECClass">
            <owl:class rdf:about="{concat('http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1#', @typeName)}" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </owl:Ontology>
</xsl:template>
```

or perhaps a bit more elegant:

```
<xsl:variable name="myURL">http://www.semanticweb.org/aman.prasad/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-1</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="{$myURL}">
        <xsl:for-each select="ECSchema/ECClass">
            <owl:class rdf:about="{$myURL}#{@typeName}" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </owl:Ontology>
</xsl:template>
```